# Relation between $(hkl)$ indices and the integers $m_i$ in $\vec{G}=\sum_i m_i\vec{b}_i$?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals, x-ray-crystallography

Can somebody explain how to establish the connection between Miller indices $(h,k,l)$ of a crystal plane and the triplet of integers $(m_1,m_2,m_3)$ that appear in the linear combination  $$\vec{G}=m_1\vec{b}_1+m_2\vec{b}_2+m_3\vec{b}_3.$$ Here, ${\vec G}$ is the reciprocal lattice vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A crystal plane with Miller indices $(hkl)$ is orthogonal to the reciprocal lattice vector $\vec G = h \vec b_1 + k \vec b_2 + l \vec b_3$.

Comment: Can you explain what it means for a vector in the reciprocal lattice space to be orthogonal to a plane in the direct lattice space?

Comment: @mithusengupta123 In crystallography, the direct and reciprocal lattices and their corresponding vectors are identified as subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3$, and they inherit the obvious inner product structure from that.